# Any Technical Issue why I shouldn't use jqQgrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

We are about to replace a largish codebase that uses ExtJS grid and are planning on using jqGrid. Just wondering if there are known issues that would stop us doing this.

Im not looking for opionion if its good or if there are better options. I'm looking for people who have used it that have either had a good experience or even better run into some technical issues upon use case or scale or similar that may make me reconsider.

Comment: I can't comment on jqGrid as I haven't used it. However, if you're looking to "downsize" for a smaller/faster/more efficient implementation I've really been enjoying wijmo lately which is based on jQuery UI. No the wijmo grid can't make toast, but it sure does do grids!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found it to be an excellent library overall. Every once in a while I run into a minor bug that either I can fix myself, or I can backport the fix from Github, or just wait until the next version when it'll probably be fixed anyway. If it meets your requirements in terms of features and use cases, I would say definitely go for it. Technically the plugin is top notch in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps you, it is being used in several large web-based companies for administration purposes. I remember dealing with jqGrid on a couple of interviews.

Comment: Yes, but so is ExtJS. Being used by someone else doesn't really say as much to me as an aggregate opinion from a number of developer's. There's always going to be *someone* who will use any component. If you have some experience with jqGrid it'd be more valuable to hear feedback from that.

Answer (score 0):

I was using jqGrid 3.7 in a huge project with quite complex requirements (e.g. initialize grid on a hidden tab, update grid on demand with json data, custom sorting/selecting actions, re-serialisation of grid data to json, pagination, configurable grid height).

In the beginning, everything looked fine, but when we added more functionality, jqGrid was exposing a lot of flaws. The jqGrid API is quite bloated and there are no tests at all in the codebase. This let us finally drop jqGrid for another grid solution (which met our requirements a bit better, but couldn't satisfy us either).

jqGrid has an active development community and frequent releases, so it might be possible that you can hack around its glitches. But for a really complex grid, I'd go for a MVC-based solution - this allows you to keep your grid data in a separate model that can be re-used by other UI components (e.g. a diagram widget)

**UPDATE: Reasons for dropping jqGrid**

We dropped jqGrid for [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid), which was/is(?) also used by [StackExchange](http://data.stackexchange.com).

The main reasons for dropping jQGrid were the inability to initialize the grid on a hidden jQuery UI Tab, styling difficulties and the desire to use a common data model for all of our widgets instead of writing out dozens of different models for every data visualisation widget we use (diagram, grid, treeview, etc.).

SlickGrid brought us performance improvements through its virtual rendering technology but had its own glitches (e.g. selections in paged grids not working proberly). Right now we are testing the [grid component in KendoUI](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html) and maybe we will also consider the new [grid widget of jQuery UI](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/34246941/Grid).

Comment: You wrote about "another grid solution". Which one you have chosen? Do you remember which problems exactly you could not solve with jqGrid?

Comment: Yes can you provide more detail on both the problem and alternative.

Comment: I am curious as well - which grid solution did you end up going with?

Answer (score 0):

Full Disclosure: I work For [Kendo UI](http://kendoui.com)

The Kendo UI grid is designed to be lightweight and extremely fast.  It currently has a wide and robust feature set with multiple sorting, grouping and custom toolbars.

In addition, Kendo UI has a [DataSource](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datasource/index.html) which can really ease the process of handeling CRUD operations when doing editing with a grid solution.

Not to mention that you get all of the other widgets that come with Kendo UI.  You can also get data vizualization components and see the preview of the native mobile suite coming after the new year.

http://kendoui.com/mobile

Comment: Can you actually answer the question: `"Any Technical Issue why I shouldn't use jqQgrid"`? This just sounds like a shameless plug as it is.

Comment: My comment was simply supporting information for the mention of Kendo UI above.  It's good to have all the facts when making a decision so that you can choose the right tool for the job!